# Python 3 | str still being identified as an int after conversion

Tags: python, string, integer

So I'm certain I've committed a cardinal sin of some kind to have this kind of error, but basically I chopped up a file and converted it wordwise into a list. In this program, I run a function to change everything in the list into an integer, and if it can't be changed, I skip over it. Afterwards, I append every integer to a new list as long as it is larger than 999.

For the next part, I need a standardized length, and python automatically removes leading zeroes, so my idea was to convert the integers back to a string, find their length, and add zeroes up to 10 digits, but regardless of what I try I keep getting:

```
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phdirDEBUG.py", line 48, in <module>
    if len(i) == 10:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Note the class str, I even check right before I run the leading zeroes adding function to make sure that the item in the list is a string, yet the error log still says it's an integer. I feel like there is a best practice I'm missing here.

```
  #Puts file into a list word by word.
for eachWord in error_file:
  error_lst.extend(eachWord.split())

def str_to_int():
#Converts all string values to integers
  for i in range(0, len(error_lst)):
    try:
      error_lst[i] = int(error_lst[i])
      return error_lst
    except:
      continue

#Everything that is converted to an integer is added to a new list
int_lst = []
for eachword in str_to_int():
  if type(eachword) == int and eachword > 999:
    int_lst.append(eachword)

def int_to_string():
#And then turned back into a string.
  for i in range(0, len(int_lst)):
    try:
      int_lst[i] = str(int_lst[i])
      return int_lst
    except:
      print("Error converting integer to a string!")

print(type(int_to_string()[0]))

for i in range(0, len(int_to_string())):
  if len(i) == 10:
    continue
  elif len(i) == 9:
    i.zfill(1)
  elif len(i) == 8:
    i.zfill(2)
  elif len(i) == 7:
    i.zfill(3)
  elif len(i) == 6:
    i.zfill(4)
  elif len(i) == 5:
    i.zfill(5)
  elif len(i) == 4:
    i.zfill(6)
  else:
    print("This is awkward. I didn't expect there to be an invoice number less than 4 characters long. :/")
```

Comment: You are returning as soon as *one* list element is converted to an `int`. You need to wait until *after* the loop has completed to return the entire list.

Comment: Note, `range()` function doesn't generate strings.

Comment: (Given that you are modifying a list in-place, there's no need to return anything at all.)

Comment: You are doing `for i in range(...):` and then `if len(i)...:`. `i` is an int...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to itarate over int_list, you can just write:

```
for i in int_to_string():
```

no need to use the range here.
there is still a problem with your code in the int_to_string function. the return statement will stop the function at the first element that can be converted to string.